# Symfony3 mongoDB configurtion

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony

I am working with symfony3 and trying to set up MongoDB. I am following the Symfony documentation [Symf Doc Mongo](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMongoDBBundle/index.html).

In Install the bundle with Composer section of this Doc its been suggested to install these two bundles:

```
        "doctrine/mongodb-odm": "~1.0",
    "doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle": "~3.0"
```

I am trying to do just that and but when i composer update i get these errors:

```
Problem 1
- doctrine/mongodb-odm 1.0.0 requires doctrine/mongodb ~1.2 -> satisfiable by doctrine/mongodb[1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 1.3.0].
- doctrine/mongodb-odm 1.0.1 requires doctrine/mongodb ~1.2 -> satisfiable by doctrine/mongodb[1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 1.3.0].
- doctrine/mongodb-odm 1.0.2 requires doctrine/mongodb ~1.2 -> satisfiable by doctrine/mongodb[1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 1.3.0].
- doctrine/mongodb-odm 1.0.3 requires doctrine/mongodb ~1.2 -> satisfiable by doctrine/mongodb[1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 1.3.0].
- doctrine/mongodb-odm 1.0.4 requires doctrine/mongodb ~1.2 -> satisfiable by doctrine/mongodb[1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 1.3.0].
- doctrine/mongodb-odm 1.0.5 requires doctrine/mongodb ~1.2 -> satisfiable by doctrine/mongodb[1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 1.3.0].
- doctrine/mongodb 1.3.0 requires ext-mongo ^1.5 -> the requested PHP extension mongo is missing from your system.
- doctrine/mongodb 1.2.2 requires ext-mongo ^1.2.12 -> the requested PHP extension mongo is missing from your system.
- doctrine/mongodb 1.2.1 requires ext-mongo ^1.2.12 -> the requested PHP extension mongo is missing from your system.
- doctrine/mongodb 1.2.0 requires ext-mongo ^1.2.12 -> the requested PHP extension mongo is missing from your system.
- Installation request for doctrine/mongodb-odm ~1.0 -> satisfiable by doctrine/mongodb-odm[1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2, 1.0.3, 1.0.4, 1.0.5].
```

I dont understand where i should go from here.

Comment: You need to install and enable the [Mongo extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mongo.php).

Comment: I did just that witb brew homebrew/php/php56-mongodb and enabled the extension in php.ini still get the same error

Comment: Maybe you have enabled the extension for web and not for cli?

Comment: what do you mean for the web not for cli..?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should also install `alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter` package by typing `composer require alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter` and manually add `"provide"` section, if not exists, with content:

```
   "provide": {
        "ext-mongo": "1.6.14"
    },
```